# PHP script works on localhost but not IIS server

Tags: php, iis, twitter

I have a PHP script that displays Tweets embedded in a site I built out on my local machine. When I uploaded the site to my IIS 8.0 server, the PHP script no longer works and I receive this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\i360_new\footer.php on line 76

The script is:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

    /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "xxxxx",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxxxx",
        'consumer_key' => "xxxxx",
        'consumer_secret' => "xxxxx"
    );


    /** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
    /** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
    $getfield = '?screen_name=interactive360&count=1';
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
    foreach($string as $items)
        {
            echo $items['text']."<br />";
        }
?>
```

I thought it might be a PHP version issue but my local machine is running 5.4.10 and my server is running 5.4.14.

Comment: Does that server have JSON support enabled?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: You mean that someone would disable `json_decode`? Is that even possible?

Comment: before your `foreach` line put a `var_dump($string)` to see what results you are getting as it doesn't appear it is what you are expecting.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I'm not sure? I assumed it was but if it's not enabled by default than no, I haven't enabled JSON support. Is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: @dirt I added the suggested line and it just made my footer disappear.

Comment: The `$string` variable obviously is not what you think it is. Figure out where it comes from and, for goodness sake, make it a habit to always check return values for their type, especially when the return value depends on data from outside your application. Also, learn to understand error messages. The error you get tells you what it wrong.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'm not sure if I follow. I'm confused on why it would work on my local server but not my IIS server. Since it works on my local server there wouldn't be an issue with the actual code right?

Comment: Coding is environment dependent, that is, your different environments can have different configurations both at the OS and Application layers i.e. Apache/IIS and PHP configuration

Comment: @user715564 That only holds true if your local server is identical to your IIS server. In this case it is probably because your Twitter object cannot retrieve the JSON file (the connection is blocked somewhere, maybe by PHP, the OS or a firewall), or that what is retrieved is invalid JSON. Both would make `json_decode` choke, which means that `foreach` gives you an error saying that it cannot loop over it (probably because it is `null`, which `json_decode` returns on failure). You need to look at where `$string` came from, to see where the problem is, and then take it from there.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem sorry I did not see their PHP version at the end of their question. Before 5.2 this did not come as default and sometimes that is the reason so I asked. But of course 5.4 has it bundled

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yeah it's version 5.4 on both servers. I also have JSON and CURL enabled on the IIS server. The problem is, the $string variable is returning empty which is causing the error. Whey it's returning empty...I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an SSL/CURL issue. In the TwitterAPIExchange.php file, I had to add these two lines to the CURL options array:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
```